# React-admin keep form data after create view submit

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

In a react-admin `Create` form, is there a way to keep whatever info the user typed into the form to stay on the screen after the user clicks `Save`?

I want to re-use the same form data that they entered to create the another record.

Comment: Hi Wayne. What do you mean by "keep the data"?

Comment: @AxelJunes I want whatever they typed into the form to stay on the screen after clicking Save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

According to this [PR](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2082/files#diff-7a968f27f20d41fcc1788bee45f2d530R6), it looks like `react-admin` clears the form state after Create / Edit Forms submission.

Unfortunately, I didn't find out a documented way, how to prevent this default behavior.

From the PR, I understand that passing `redirect={false}` and `to={{ state: { skipFormReset: true } }}` may prevent the form state clearing. Something like that:

```
<CreateButton redirect={false} to={{ state: { skipFormReset: true } }} />
```

Another option (a workaround) - after creation, you can try to update the current create form `defaultValue` with the data you already filled (created).

---

**Original answer:**
`redux-form` will destroy your form and its state (data) automatically when your component is unmounted.

You can prevent this default form behaviour and keep your form's state after unmounting, as passing:

```
destroyOnUnmount: false
```

[destroyOnUnmount documentation](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-destroyonunmount-boolean-code-optional-).

Comment: This didn't work on React-Admin v2.9.2. I passed `destroyOnUnmount={false}` to my `<SimpleForm>` which was nested inside of a `<Create>` component. I used React devtools to confirm that `destroyOnUnmount={false}` was indeed passed on to the `<ReduxForm>` component that react-admin generates. After I submitted the form though, the redux slice for the form was cleared out as were the visible form inputs.

Comment: @WayneBloss are you redirected on a new location after form submission? Also what redux action clears the form? Please try to pass `redirect={false}` to your form, because on any redirect `react-admin` resets the form. [Redirect credits](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#redirection-after-submission). [Here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2082/files#diff-7a968f27f20d41fcc1788bee45f2d530R6) I found out, that `react-admin` reset the form, after location change.

Comment: @jordan-env I originally had `redirect="create"` (which is the form I'm coming from) but I tried it again just now passing `<SimpleForm redirect={false} destroyOnUnmount={false} ...` and that doesn't work either.

Comment: A workaround would be on create, to update the current create form `defaultValue` with the data you already filled. Can you please create a simple sandbox? That will help up us to support you better.

Comment: @WayneBloss if you redirect to the same create page, after create, it should not reset your form, according to this [PR](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2322/files).

Comment: @WayneBloss can you please try to add `to` and `redirect` properties to your Create form button, something like that:  `<CreateButton redirect={false} to={{ state: { skipFormReset: true } }}  />`. Also please make sure you pass `redirect={false}` to the form too.

Comment: @jordan-env I actually don't have a Create button, I'm linking directly to `${resource-name}/create` in my custom appbar menu for this particular resource. I'm also loading defaults from my server as you can see in [this issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3202) - However, you can see the codesandbox one responder created worked (at least at one time it did). The workaround you mentioned should work for normal screens though so I will mark this answered. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up converting my "create-only" resource to a custom page where I don't use `<Create>` or `<SimpleForm>`.

Answer (score 0):

Before updating react-admin to v3.19 `redirect={false}` did the job and preserved the inputs.

After update:
`redirect={false}` : remains at current the route and clears the form (does not re-render, and forms are cleared on default)

`redirect={create/edit}` : remains at the current create-route, keeps entries in inputforms as it's component is rendered, and input-values are presumably taken from some internal state handling.