# How to prefill certain fields on a create form using previous data with react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm using react-admin(3.1.2) and I'm implementing a "Save and Add" button to allow bulk creation, as documented [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#toolbar).

I'm trying to prefill **certain** fields on the next create form based on the inputs of the previous form. How could I achieve that?

**Sandbox to have a look**

I created a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wiles-jbbjt), feel free to fork it. The expected behaviour is to prefill the field `teaser` with the previous teaser value when you click the "Save and Add" button on the Post Create page (PostCreate.js).

My Create Component looks like this for the moment :

```
const PostCreateToolbar = props => (
  <Toolbar {...props}>
    <SaveButton
      label="post.action.save_and_edit"
      redirect="edit"
      submitOnEnter={true}
    />
    <SaveButton
      label="post.action.save_and_add"
      redirect={false}
      submitOnEnter={false}
      variant="text"
    />
  </Toolbar>
);

const PostCreate = ({ permissions, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm
        toolbar={<PostCreateToolbar />}
        validate={values => {
          const errors = {};
          ["title", "teaser"].forEach(field => {
            if (!values[field]) {
              errors[field] = "Required field";
            }
          });

          return errors;
        }}
      >
        <TextInput autoFocus source="title" />
        <TextInput source="teaser" fullWidth={true} multiline={true} />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
};
```

**What I tried**

This [example](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#prefilling-a-create-record) doesn't fit my need as I need to **save first** the current form before redirecting to the new form.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499097/react-admin-keep-form-data-after-create-view-submit/56541363#56541363) does not work either as I just need **some of the fields** (not all) to be prefilled.

I also tried to redirect to the create form passing in parameters the fields to prefill using prop `redirect="/posts/create?teaser=aa"` in the SaveButton Component but then the new form is filled with **all** the data from the previous form.

Any help on this one would be super appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To pre-fill some fields in the Create form, pass a stringified `source` parameter in the url. You can set this URL in the `SaveButton` redirect *function*:

```
redirect={(redirectTo, basePath, is, data) => `/posts/create?source={"title":"${data.title}"}`}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. There seems to be two problems to this solution. First, data.title is not defined and second, looks like when redirect prop is set to something different as `"false"`, the state after submitting the form is still filled with all the values from the previous form. See ths [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-firefly-lg6ix) that reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Works great with `const redirect = useRedirect(); redirect(\`/posts/create?source...\`);`. `data.title` is just an example, @AlixDeschamps

Answer (score -1):

My two cents:
I found out that if I change the **record** object of **props** (props.record) I can manipulate the content of the field I want to set.

The problem is that **record** is read only and it is **null** so I couldn't manipulate its properties.

My solution was to add the following line before `<Create {...props}>`:

```
const createProps = { ...props, record: { myProperty: 'myValue' } }
```

and then

```
<Create {...createProps}>
```

you can just set `record: {}` for later manipulation in an internal functional component, but remember to pass the props of the function to the internal component too:

```
const myCreateComponent = props => {
       const createProps = { ...props, record: { myProperty: 'myValue (or a value you sent to this function along with props - (props, myObjectWithSomeValuesToUse) => ...thisFunction)' } }
       return (
          <Create {...createProps}>
              <MySimpleForm>
          </Create>
       )
};

const MySimpleForm = props => {
   props.record.myOtherProperty = 'myOtherValue'
   return (
       <SimpleForm {...props}>
          <TextInput source="myProperty"/>
          ...content
          <TextInput source="myOtherProperty"/>
       </SimpleForm>
   )
};
```

**props** of MySimpleForm will have myProperty value already set in the **record** object (`props.record.myProperty`), the other property you set will be there too and it all should reflect in the UI and in the data of the **transform** function of the **Create** component